# How do I post both file and data at once in single route in node.js?

Tags: node.js, multipartform-data, multer

I am trying to upload both the image and data in a single node.js route 
I found there is something called multipart/form-data but I am unable to use it
I am confused about uploading both data and file can anyone upload the sample code.

However, I am able to upload it by pulling the ID of the Task model and update, Here is the code I did

```
router.post('/task/avatar/:id', upload.single('taskavatar'), async (req, res) => {

    try {
        const task = await Task.findById(req.params.id)
        console.log(task["name"])
        if (!task) {
            return res.status(404).send({ "status": false })
        }
        task["taskavatar"] = req.file.buffer
        await task.save()
        res.send({ "message": "success" })
    } catch (err) { }
}, (error, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(400).send({ error: error.message })
})
```

Comment: From the doc: ***Multer adds a body object and a file or files object to the request object. The body object contains the values of the text fields of the form, the file or files object contains the files uploaded via the form.***  Are you not able to use `req.body` for your data?

Comment: can you provide me with a sample snippet? I'm firing the request on postman

Comment: Examples right here in the doc: https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#usage.  You don't show what your client-side looks like so I'm not sure what else to suggest.

Comment: I'm firing the request on postman here is what I followed, request=>post & body=>form-data, here the key for an image is **taskavatar** and what will be the **data** key, in code where do I mention the key of the data value

Comment: `let value = req.body.key` where `key` is whatever name you gave the attribute in the form data.  I don't know Postman.  Might try following the exact example from the doc with an actual form post in a web page.